# A specific short-circuiting example in C

Tags: c, logical-operators, short-circuiting, logical-or, logical-and

I understand the basic concept of short-circuiting with operators, but why does

```
int i = 0, j = -1, k = 1, m;
m = !(i++ && ++j) || ++k;
printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, k, m);
```

have 1 -1 1 1 as an output? Specifically, why is j == -1 instead of 0?

I know similar questions have been already asked, but I don't understand this specific example which I didn't find anywhere.

Comment: Why should `j` be 0?

Comment: `i++` is false, so the `&&` conjunction is false and `++j` is not evaluated.

Comment: ++j is evaluated as -1 + 1 = 0? I feel like I've made some obvious mistake in my thinking

Comment: The post increment `i++` returns the original value of i (before the increment) which is zero. So the part after `&&` is not evaluated (because of short cut).

Comment: @dxiv: you mean that `i` is false, so `i && ...` is not evaluated, en so forth.

Comment: oh jesus, I feel so dumb now. I was looking at this problem for like 10 minutes without realizing that I evaluated i++ as ++i in my head.
Edit: guess I'm tired as hell, eh

Comment: @DavidIlic: can you compile this into ASM code, so that we can have a look?

Comment: @Dominique I meant the expression `i++` which evaluates to `0`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand what's happening now. Made a mistake in my head

Comment: @dxiv: `i` equals 0, so `i && ...` is not evaluated, and `i++` is not evaluated, or how else can `i++` be 0 if `i` is 0?

Comment: @Dominique Of course `i++` *is* evaluated, how else could the compiler determine the value of the conjunction. This is consistent with OP's value of `1` for `i` after the evaluation.

Comment: @dxiv: in his answer, Pmg states that `i = -1`, where's that coming from?

Comment: @Dominique That was used as an example in pmg's answer. OP's post shows `i == 1` on the last line.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason not to write code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = -1;
i++;         // value of expression is -1
             // side effect is changing i to 0
if (i++) ;   // value of `i++` is zero; the if will not "trigger"

i = 0;
if (i++ && foo) ; // i++ has value of zero (false)
                  // so false && <anything> is false
                  // so foo is not evaluated
```

Comment: Yep, I get it now. Thanks

Comment: I don't: why is `i` equal to -1?

Comment: I made it `-1` for the example, so that I wouldn't have to make it `0` twice.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the postfix increment operator is the value of its operand before incrementing.

So the value of the expression i++ is equal to 0 because the variable i was initialized by 0.

So as the value of the sub-expression `i++` is `0` then the sub-expression `++j` in this expression

```
(i++ && ++j)
```

is not evaluated and the value of the expression itself is `0`.

Applying the negation operator

```
!(i++ && ++j)
```

you will get `1` (logical true). So the sub-expression `++k` of the expression

```
!(i++ && ++j) || ++k
```

will not be evaluated.

As a result the value of the whole expression is equal to `1` that is assigned to the variable `m`.

```
m = !(i++ && ++j) || ++k;
```

On the other hand as it was pointed out in the beginning the expression `i++` was evaluated. So after this statement `i` will be equal to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`int i = 0, j = -1, k = 1, m;`

`!(i++ && ++j) || ++k;` ==> only `i++` will be evaluated, `j` and `k` will not be evaluated

lets just say we are substituting the values of variables, then the expression becomes as below.

`!(0 && ++ -1) || ++1`

step 1:
`!(0 && ++ -1)` ==> for `&&` operator if left side operand is False then we dont need to check for right side operand, so `-1` wont be incremented, so value of `j` will be `-1` itself.

and hence the left side expression before `||` becomes `!(0)`

step 2:
`!(0) || ++1`

now `!(0)` will be 1 , so for `||` operator if left side operand is TRUE , then no need to go for right side operand, then `++k` will not be executed.

`m = 1 || ++1` ==> `1`

since only `i++` is evaluated , it will change its value to `1`
so the out put is : `1 -1 1 1`